# Load testing of application based on MVC using Web performance test in VSTS2012

Tags: visual-studio, performance-testing

I'm doing load testing of a web application using VSTS2012, which is designed on MVC, & Telerik Controls, I created a web performance test, when I'm re-running the same test it fails giving following error on Form Submit.

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
X-AspNetMvc-Version : 4.0
X-UA-Compatible : IE=edge
Content-Length : 241
Cache-Control : private
Content-Type : text/html; charset=utf-8
Date : Mon, 12 May 2014 07:22:45 GMT
Server : Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version : 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By : ASP.NET
```

Can some one please help, it is recording everything correctly but not able to run properly.

Also please suggest, is there any different way for load testing of an application which is based on MVC

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific answer to this question as there are many, many possible reasons.

Commonly this error occurs because dynamic data has not been handled properly in the web test. Visual Studio detects many dynamic parameters but cannot detect all the clever things that web site designers do. For example, the response to a login request contains a value that must be returned as a form parameter in all subsequent request within that logged-in session. The fault could be that the actual requests being sent contain the value for the recorded session, not the new session. Sending an old value may confuse the web site leading to the "Internal Server Error" response.

One solution is to record two web tests that are, as nearly as possible, identical. Then compare the two ".webtest" file with a text comparison program. Sometimes it may be necessary to record additional almost identical tests but, for example, logging in as a different user. There will be some differences, eg in think times and GUID, that should be ignored. But there may also be significant differences in the requests to be sent. Having found differences, search for where the values are first seen in the responses from the web site. Use an extraction rule to put the value into a context parameter and then insert that context parameter into the requests that need it.